# Regex to match words, special characters and a date

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for the string which contains in order:

- alphabets
- a special character
- date (dd/mm/yy)

e.g.

```
Payments - received by 04/13/13
```

Could any one help me out on this? I tried the following `[a-z]* - [a-z]* 99/99/99` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]* - [a-zA-Z]* [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regular expression in Java:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".+ - .+\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d");
```

To check if the string matches:

```
String str = "Payments - received by 04/13/13";
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println("the string matches!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 9s with `d`s, d is a placeholder for `[0-9]`.
Also `[a-z]` is not equal to `[A-Za-z]`.

Of course this will still match invalid dates like the 35th of the 99th month

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but there are a couple issues:

- [a-z] only matches lower case characters. You can use \w for any number/letter, or just [a-zA-Z] for lower and upper case characters.
- To get spaces in there, you can either use [\w ] or [a-zA-Z ] (notice extra space at the end)
- the 9 matches literally the character 9. You can use \d to match any digit.

Try this instead:

```
[a-zA-z ]* - [a-zA-Z ]* \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a space in the ```[]```